# Images and layers (HTML5, canvas, JS, CSS ??)

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, transparent

I have two layers one on another top. First layers is background, second layer is flower. How I can know on what layer clicked.

1. If I clicked on background result it's good return first layer place where clicked: [image]
2. If I clicked on flower result it's good return second layer place where clicked: [image]
3. If I **clicked on background near flower** result it's bad return second layer place where clicked: [image]

3.1 I get second layer because actually image is bigger, because image have transparent place: [image]

For test use `JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbkhtvmo/1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a transparent SVG path layer that covers the flower and make that the flower click layer, then make everything else the background click layer.

Comment: maybe possible just ignore transparent place

Answer (score 1):

Use clientX and clientY to get the position of the mouse in the window.You can also do that with jQuery offset to get the position.

**jQuery example that I found useful on stackoverflow:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('imageElement').click(function(e) {
 var offset = $(this).offset();
 alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
 alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
 });
});
```